# What is the meaning of the pipe symbol here?

Tags: algorithms, automata, discrete-mathematics, distributed-systems

I am reading Distributed Algorithms by Nancy Lynch. In chapter 16, I came across the pipe symbol. Does this mean the same as "or" in some programming languages or could someone explain that line please?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a standard notation in mathematics, called the [set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)#Set-builder_notation).

Basically, it means: "the set of all $(m,i)$ such that $(m,j)\in T$".